# In visual studio images are shown but in IIS express not

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

When I run my website in visual studio, images are shown, but in IIS express not.

My code for loading image is:

```
    string strRootRelativePath = "~/Images/" + oTable[0].myImage;
    string strPath = Server.MapPath(strRootRelativePath);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(strPath))
    {
        img.ImageUrl = strPath;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check the paths that are rendered in the markup.  Use F12/DevTools. If the paths are correct, check permissions (what is the HTTP return code of the request to the server for the images)?

Comment: Check Console & Network section in browser dev tools, there are some useful information there. It depends on `oTable[0].myImage` content when performing image request.